# Given a quadratic extension $K/F$, is there a quadratic extension $L/K$ such that $ \operatorname{Gal}(L'/F)=D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a number field (or a function field with constants $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $2 \nmid q$). If $L$ is some extension such that $[L:F]=4$ and $ \operatorname{Gal}(L'/F)=D_4$, the dihedral group with 8 elements, then there is a unique quadratic extension $K$ of $F$ between $F$ and $L$.

Does this at least in part go the other way? That is,

> Given a field $F$ as above and a quadratic extension $K/F$, is there at least one quadratic extension $L/K$ such that $ \operatorname{Gal}(L'/F)=D_4$?

Comment: What is $L'$ w.r.t. $L$?

Comment: It has to be the Galois closure. Given degree $4$ polynomials are radical you should be able to find a few polynomials of $F[t,x]$ whose specialization $t=a$ are all the dihedral polynomials of degree $4$, their discriminant will be polynomials of $t$

Comment: You can find a solution here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2046653/300700 : first consider a biquadratic extension L/F containing your quadratic K, then construct a quadratic extension E/L s.t. E/F is galois of degree 8. There is a precise criterion for E/F to have Galois group $\cong D_4$. Walking backwards, you see how to construct L.