# Given a galois group find the polynomial

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

What I have in mind in order to make it more concrete are the groups of order 8. We know that there are 5 groups of order 8 in total, 3 abelian and 2 non-abelian and we know their full structure as well. We also know that they can be thought of as the Galois group of some extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ (for example every p-group has that property, but here the situation is much more trivial I think to need such a theorem).

My intuition tells me that there is not a single type of polynomials for which those groups can be realised as Galois groups of those polynomials. For example take $D_4$, the dihedral group of the square. Now $D_4$ can be thought of a Galois group of $f(x)=x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ or of a polynomial of degree 8 $f=x^8−3x^5−x^4+3x^3+1$, so even the degree of the polynomial is not fixed.

So my question is certainly not to find all the polynomials for which their Galois group is $D_4$, but find at least one.

To put it simply, my question is this. Given a finite group H which you know it is Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$, if you know the group's structure/representation etc, is there any way to find a polynomial whose Galois group is H? If yes, what part of the group's structure do you need?

For the groups of order 8 for example, $D_4$ is $f(x)=x^4-2$, for $\mathbb{Z}_8$ my guess would be the cyclotomic $\phi_8=x^4+1$ and what's left is $\mathbb{Z_2}\times \mathbb{Z_4}$, $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$, which are abelian and the quaternion $Q_4$ which is non-abelian. I 'd like to think that if I work on it I 'd probably be able to find polynomials for the abelian groups but i have no idea what i would do for the non-abelian.

Comment: Deciding whether a group is a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ is a hard problem, called the [inverse Galois problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem).

Comment: @lhf Yeah I am aware of that and i know I am bordering to this open problem, but I think that if you know everything about the group's structure then you re still in a safe zone. At least in the trivial cases of groups of order 8 i suppose everything 's been solved. For $S_n$ and $A_n$ theese cases have also been trivially answered so I 'd like to think that in the cases that you know everything about the group, there would be some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For groups of smaller order like $8$ it seems to be much easier just to classify the Galois groups of cubics and quartics, as Keith Conrad is doing in his note [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiJrP-EwIzaAhWHZ1AKHTlEDQIQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgaloistheory%2Fcubicquartic.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0-nszsOcXrbQQd3i0CCOeS). So for quartics, the only group of order $8$ which arises is $D_4$, realized by $x^4+4x^2-2$, see Example $3.10$.
Similarly, we easily find a polynomial with Galois group $Q_8$, see for example here:

[Galois group and the Quaternion group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248224/galois-group-and-the-quaternion-group)